# Subsetting data based on a value within ids in r

Tags: r, split, conditional-statements, subset

I'm trying to subset a dataset based on two criteria. Here is a snapshot of my data:

```
ids <-  c(1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3,3)
seq <-  c(1,2,3,4,5,6, 1,2,3,4,5,6, 1,2,3,4,5,6)
type <- c(1,1,5,1,1,1, 1,1,1,8,1,1, 1,1,1,1,1,1)
    data <- data.frame(ids, seq, type)

   ids seq type
1    1   1    1
2    1   2    1
3    1   3    5
4    1   4    1
5    1   5    1
6    1   6    1
7    2   1    1
8    2   2    1
9    2   3    1
10   2   4    8
11   2   5    1
12   2   6    1
13   3   1    1
14   3   2    1
15   3   3    1
16   3   4    1
17   3   5    1
18   3   6    1
```

`ids` is the student id, `seq` is the sequence of the questions (items) students take. `type` refers to the type of the question. `1`  is simple, `5` or `8` is the complicated items. What I would like to do is to generate 1st variable(`complex`) as to whether or not student has a complicated item(`type=5|8`). Then I would like to get:

```
   > data
   ids seq type complex
1    1   1    1       1
2    1   2    1       1
3    1   3    5       1
4    1   4    1       1
5    1   5    1       1
6    1   6    1       1
7    2   1    1       1
8    2   2    1       1
9    2   3    1       1
10   2   4    8       1
11   2   5    1       1
12   2   6    1       1
13   3   1    1       0
14   3   2    1       0
15   3   3    1       0
16   3   4    1       0
17   3   5    1       0
18   3   6    1       0
```

The second step is to split data within students. 
`(a)` For the student who has non-complex items (`complex=0`), I would like to split the dataset from half point and get this below:

```
>simple.split.1
    ids seq type   complex
13   3   1    1       0
14   3   2    1       0
15   3   3    1       0

>simple.split.2
    ids seq type   complex
16   3   4    1       0
17   3   5    1       0
18   3   6    1       0
```

`(b)` for the students who have complex items (`complex=1`), I would like to set the complex item as a cutting point and split the data from there. So the data should look like this (excluding complex item):

```
   >complex.split.1
    ids seq type   complex
1    1   1    1       1
2    1   2    1       1
7    2   1    1       1
8    2   2    1       1
9    2   3    1       1

    >complex.split.2
    ids seq type   complex
4    1   4    1       1
5    1   5    1       1
6    1   6    1       1
11   2   5    1       1
12   2   6    1       1
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer using the `tidyverse`, here's an approach:

```
ids <-  c(1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3,3)
seq <-  c(1,2,3,4,5,6, 1,2,3,4,5,6, 1,2,3,4,5,6)
type <- c(1,1,5,1,1,1, 1,1,1,8,1,1, 1,1,1,1,1,1)
data <- data.frame(ids, seq, type)

step1.data <- data %>%
  group_by(ids) %>%
  mutate(complex = ifelse(any(type %in% c(5,8)), 1, 0)) %>%
  ungroup()

simple.split.1 <- step1.data %>%
  filter(complex == 0) %>%
  group_by(ids) %>%
  filter(seq <= mean(seq)) %>% #if you happen to have more than 6 questions in seq, this gives the midpoint
  ungroup()

simple.split.2 <- step1.data %>%
  filter(complex == 0) %>%
  group_by(ids) %>%
  filter(seq > mean(seq)) %>%
  ungroup()

complex.split.1 <- step1.data %>%
  filter(complex == 1) %>%
  arrange(ids, seq) %>%
  group_by(ids) %>%
  filter(seq < min(seq[type %in% c(5,8)])) %>%
  ungroup()

complex.split.2 <- step1.data %>%
  filter(complex == 1) %>%
  arrange(ids, seq) %>%
  group_by(ids) %>%
  filter(seq > min(seq[type %in% c(5,8)])) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and solution @Kyle. this works really good.

Comment: happy to help out!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do it using `data.table`, `zoo` packages and `split` function:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

setDT(data)[, complex := ifelse(type == 5 | type == 8, 1, NA_integer_), by = ids][, complex := na.locf(na.locf(complex, na.rm=FALSE), na.rm=FALSE, fromLast=TRUE), by = ids][, complex := ifelse(is.na(complex), 0, complex)] ## set data to data.table & add a flag 1 where type is 5 or 8 ## carry forward and backward of complex flag ## replace na values in complex column with 0

data <- data[!(type == 5 | type == 8), ] ## removing rows where type equals 5 or 8

complex <- split(data, data$complex) ## split data based on complex flag

complex_0 <- as.data.frame(complex$`0`) ## saving as data frame based on complex flag
complex_1 <- as.data.frame(complex$`1`)

split(complex_0, cut(complex_0$seq, 2)) ## split into equal parts
split(complex_1, cut(complex_1$seq, 2))


#$`(0.995,3.5]`
#   ids seq type complex
#1   3   1    1       0
#2   3   2    1       0
#3   3   3    1       0

#$`(3.5,6]`
#   ids seq type complex
#4   3   4    1       0
#5   3   5    1       0
#6   3   6    1       0



    #$`(0.995,3.5]`
#   ids seq type complex
#1   1   1    1       1
#2   1   2    1       1
#6   2   1    1       1
#7   2   2    1       1
#8   2   3    1       1

#$`(3.5,6]`
#    ids seq type complex
#3    1   4    1       1
#4    1   5    1       1
#5    1   6    1       1
#9    2   5    1       1
#10   2   6    1       1
```

Comment: thanks for your solution @sm925, the complex data has the type=8 rows but that can be removed easily. thanks for your time!

Comment: @amisos55 In requirement it was not given to remove those rows. I'll update my answer soon.